# how to get the edittext view from keyboard

Tags: android

I am designing my own keyboard and I have an additional button that I want to use to bring up the 'Edit Text' context menu. As this button is in the keyboard, this menu should popup in any application.

I searched and found two methods, registerContextMenu(view) and showContextMenu(view)

So my question is: how can i get the view (edittext view) that my keyboard is currently inputting to, so that I can attach the methods to the appropriate view?

Comment: AFAIK, you can't. Your keyboard should be running in a separate process and has no access to the `EditText`, or its context menu.

Comment: I thought so. But was wondering if there is some system call that can give me the edit-text, as at any one time, the keyboard will be active for only one edit text.

Comment: No, because the `EditText` does not exist in your process.

Comment: Hmmm...for a demo i guess i can use an EditText. Is there anyway that I can signal which context menu to show??? like choosing between the cut/copy one to the one with 'select all, select word' etc???